# Whats a good way of typecast struct member in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently using UDF to convert/parse an existing table to another.

```
SELECT
  parseMethod(path) AS Method,
  existing_column
FROM
  existing_table
```

The UDF returns a struct with a integer value like the following

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseMethod(req_path STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<method STRING, banner_id FLOAT64>
LANGUAGE js AS
"""
  var method = {}
  method = parsePath(req_path);
  return method
"""
```

But since UDF only allows returning of FLOAT64, I am stuck with a floating value for integer value. I am afraid this will cause matching/comparison issues in the future.

Is there a clean way of typecasting this integer column? All I could think was creating a temporary table and combining it with existing table with `WITH` or `JOIN` clause and then converting them to final table

Comment: can you clarify what is still a problem for you here? Mosha's answer looks really clear to me

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Doesn't Mosha's answer mean that final table would have method_id as string and not INT64? So whoever is using the table would have to cast it to INT every time.

Comment: No. What his example is - to show you how you can use that casting"technique" in your own SQL that you use to convert original table to another one. So you should "add" this to your query

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about precision - perhaps you can return banner_id as a STRING, and then parse it into INT64 inside SQL using CAST, i.e.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  STRUCT<method STRING, banner_id INT64>
    (x.method, CAST(x.banner_id AS INT64)) result
FROM
  (SELECT STRUCT<method STRING, banner_id STRING>("foo", "1234") x)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the UDF is used to convert/parse an existing table to another. So the final table should have a schema with banner_id as Integer

Comment: @dorachan2010 I think you've misunderstood the intention of this SQL snippet. It should be used to as part of building the new table, and it outputs banner_id as INT64.